# The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, .net-assembly

**The Problem**

Error when going to a specific page (in local debug): CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Here are the referenced lines of code in the error message:

Line 28:
Line 29:
Line 30:     public class _Page_Views_blah_granny_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {
Line 31:
Line 32: #line hidden

All other pages work great - this only happens when accessing one page in particular.  The reference is working on all other pages.  As far as I am able to determine, this is not a problem with the reference.

I've spent a good block of time researching this issue.

All the answers I found suggested going to web.config and putting an assembly reference to linq in system.web > configuration > assemblies.  Mine doesn't have assemblies listed and I suspect this is more for older versions.  I did it anyway.  It gave me another error saying it has no idea what to do with assemblies.

I deleted system.data.linq and added it in again.

I rebooted both VS and my computer.

My code - as generated by default by VS - has System.Linq.

**Background - This is how this started:**

The application is MVC 4, C#.

I created a new class in my DataContext, added a new controller, and created a strongly typed view.

Here is some very similar code (likely not needed, but just in case).

Two classes:

```
public class granny { 
            public string data { get; set; }
            public string criteria { get; set; }
}

public List<granny> getGranny() {
    var a = from x in grannytable
            join dx in anothertable
            on x.criteria equals dx.criteria
            select new granny {
                data = x.somenewdata;
            }; 
    return a.ToList();
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
    public ActionResult granny() {
        return View(db.getGranny());
    }
```

Nothing fancy there.

The page is a typical razor view, strongly typed "List"...it has a table that it iterates to create, dumping the data as it goes.

I am happy to provide any additional code as needed.

I have not messed with web.config.  I have not removed or tweaked any of the references on the pages.  All of the other views work marvelously.

When I run it locally, and attempt to go to /granny I get the above error.

Thanks for your help!

**THE SOLUTION**: I went into references, and for the System.Linq (or for older versions, I suppose, System.Data.Linq) and changed CopyLocal to True.

Comment: Forgetting about assemblies in the config file, does your project not just have a "normal" set of references? (In solution explorer, is there a References item?)

Comment: There certainly is.  It references System.Data.Linq.  I removed the reference and added it, thinking something got hung up there.  I'm using the included .NET System.Data.Linq.  It points to C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Linq.dll as it should.  It's worth noting that my other pages are using linq just fine.  I don't think it's a linq reference issue, because it's not a gregarious problem - it's just this one page.

Comment: can you provide a complete solution or project that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The whole solution?  Or are there specific files or properties you are interested in?

Comment: @shubniggurath A complete solution. Doesn't have to be YOUR solution per say. Just one that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: check that your namespace is correct for this class. And what is grannytable? I'm wondering if the problems is that your class's namespace is not consistent with that of your context

Comment: For any poor souls that also encounter this, editing the properties for the System.Linq > CopyLocal to True fixed it for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me:

- Navigate to the web project's References node
- Find the reference to System.Data.Linq
- Open the VS Properties Window
- In the properties window, change Copy Local: False to True

Before this, the System.Data.Linq.dll was not being copied into the bin directory. (Copying it manually into the bin directory also resolved the error)

Comment: +1 Nice one. This still holds up a year later. For anyone else, I experienced this with Umbraco 7 WebApi controller when using a dbml data context. Copy local as Chris describes does the trick. Cheers

Comment: Why does this work? Shouldn't `System.Data.Linq.dll` always be available anyway if it's referenced?

Comment: It probably should. The bug, I suppose, is that it was marked Copy Local:False. I don't know how that happens

Answer (score 9):

Try to add `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your problem view and
 `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` into `<pages>` section of web.config in your **Views** folder.

Answer (score 9):

MVC cannot compile your view on the fly. It looks like your view contains a reference to a DataContext. Adding a reference in web.config should tell the compiler to look for the file:

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0"> 
    <assemblies> 
      <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
   </assemblies> 
</compilation>
```

Note: the assembly should be added under the compilation element.

Can you share your view, controller and datacontext code?

Comment: Assemblies do not need to be added in MVC 4.